# Java sockets - weird response

Tags: java, sockets, awt, tic-tac-toe

I'm doing a simple server/client communication for my tic tac toe game. All it goes through actionPerformed where I first setIcon to the pressed button, then proceed my performTurn method (there is some win checking), then send the coordinates of the pressed button to the client and then i wait for the other player to send me data about his turn. all it goes well, but......... the first method that should be made (setIcon) is actually done after receiving data from the other player. it goes like this: Game.performTurn, Server.send, Server.receive, setIcon. do anyone know what java issue is it, that the setIcon method doesnt go first? thx lot

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    if (clickable && Game.getTurn()) {
        clickable = false;
        if (Board.player) {
            setIcon(X);
            Game.performTurn(x, y, Value.FIRST);
            try {
                Server.send(new ObjToSend(x, y));
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(XOButton.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
            try {
                ObjToSend bla = Server.recieve();
                Board.buttons[bla.getX()][bla.getY()].setIcon(O);
                Game.performTurn(bla.getX(), bla.getY(), Value.SECOND);
                Game.turn = true;
            } catch (IOException | ClassNotFoundException ex) {
                Logger.getLogger(XOButton.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
            }
```

Comment: I'm confused.  I don't see anything that immediately strikes me as "wrong" (except some naming conventions), but I also don't know of the response you're receiving back from the server - you haven't provided that detail.  What's actually going awry with this method?  (And why would a block be throwing a `ClassNotFoundException`?)

Comment: The big question is `Server.receive()` a blocking method? Meaning when you call it does it cause the thread to wait for something, this would likely be in the form or reading from a IO stream. If so that means you are blocking your EDT thread and that is never good and likely the "weird" behavior your are seeing.

Comment: I added the AWT tag because you are clearly using AWT.  If you are also using Swing, I recommend adding that tag as well.  Swing has some weird issues with threads and with the threading model not matching the documentation, and Swing experts might be able to identify the issue - for example, setIcon() may dispatch a task that includes parts queued to the main thread, which would then block until your actionPerformed() method returned.

Comment: Don't perform network operations in the event thread, in this case in the actionPerformed() method. They block, and freeze the GUI. Use a separate thread.